# CodeIgniter 2.1.4: CI_Javascript not found when linking to JQuery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter-2

I have an issue including JQuery on my CodeIgniter project. By default, Jquery is included but I can not be able to link with it. I am trying this:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'email', 'profiler', 'javascript/jquery');
```

Libraries like database, email or profiler are stored in system/libraries folder and it is ok, no problem. But jquery is in system/libraries/javascript folder and I get this error in browser.

```
Fatal error: Class 'CI_Javascript' not found in C:\Users\dani\XAMPP\htdocs\CodeIgniter_2.1.4\system\libraries\javascript\Jquery.php on line 27
```

I am working on Windows, so capitalizing is not a problem. It is like CI_Javascript class did not exist.

The only way I solved this issue was downloading JQuery manually, and later, incluiding with a link tag in HTML files but I want to autoload always, is more comfortable.

Have anyone had the same issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needn't specify jQuery in autoload, just load Javascript library.

From [from manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/javascript.html):

> Currently, the only available library is jQuery, which will automatically be loaded like this:
>
> $this->load->library('javascript');

Comment: @danigonlinea you are welcome, if You have questions on CI, I'll try to help. Have a nice day